# Ошибка обработки файлов RTF на python

Tags: python, python-3.x, кодировка, rtf

Всем добрый день!
Сломал всю голову с таким вопросом:
Написал код:

```
import pyperclip
import os
from striprtf.striprtf import rtf_to_text

rtf = open('01-08.2020.rtf').read()
text = rtf_to_text(rtf)
a = text.encode('iso-8859-1').decode('cp1251')
i = a.find('Поступ.')
if i != -1:
    a = a[:i]
pyperclip.copy(a)
```

и все работает как часы, если вначале rtf файла не стоит скрытый текст в виде "разрыва раздела"
после чего программа пишет ошибку:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 34-35: ordinal not in range(256)
```

программа явно ругается на строку, так как iso-8859-1 не может декодировать скрытый текст написанный в RTF-ке:

```
a = text.encode('iso-8859-1').decode('cp1251')
```

Так как я в питоне человек новый и понятия не имею как предварительно проверить текст на скрытые символы
решил пойти другим путем, а именно:
удалить строку на которую ругается компилятор, в итоге получился код:

```
import pyperclip
    import os
    from striprtf.striprtf import rtf_to_text
    text = rtf_to_text(rtf)
    a = text.encode('iso-8859-1').decode('cp1251')
    i = a.find('Поступ.')
    if i != -1:
        a = a[:i]
    pyperclip.copy(a)
```

Но в нем некорректно кодируется часть слов как пример:

ВЫПИСКА ÈÇ ËÈÖÅÂÎÃÎ Ñ×ÅÒÀ а должна быть ВЫПИСКА ИЗ ЛИЦЕВОГО СЧЕТА
В сухом остатке я вижу два пути либо как то проверять файл на скрытый текст перед декодированием, либо работать с "кривым" текстом и заменять некорректные буквы правильными...
Уважаемые профессионалы, если сможете помочь советом буду благодарен спасибо!!!

Comment: Попробуйте использовать только одну кодировку при обработке. Функция `rtf_to_text` принимает, обрабатывает и возвращает строку (https://github.com/joshy/striprtf/blob/73092d2322a8796444aee0c319e405ecdc770dbe/striprtf/striprtf.py#L83). Попробуйте только раз указывать кодировку. Например, в `open` указывайте кодировку явно, а то будет выбрана системная: `rtf = open('01-08.2020.rtf', encoding="utf-8").read()`, а строку с `a = text.encode('iso-8859-1').decode('cp1251')` уберите

Comment: @gil9red Спасибо, но это не помогает я с кодировкой игрался со всякой, ничего не вышло( явно striprtf не дружит со скрытыми символами - в этом главная ошибка!

Comment: Можете скинуть ссылку на файл с этой проблемой? `"удалить строку на которую ругается компилятор, в итоге получился код"` кст, по коду вы пытаетесь удалить строку после того места, где та ошибка происходит

Comment: @gil9red Магия! Так как фаил содержит данные которые я не имею права разглашать попробовал скопировать проблемную по моему мнению часть и вот к чему пришёл! Если фаил пересохранить с любым изменением  то отрабатывает он правильно! Т.е. в файле сформированном и не редактированном ошибка сохраняется.... Беда  По поводу части с удалением она работает исправно, вопрос как раз возникает до части с  i = a.find('Поступ.')
возможно какой то уникальный глюк! Попробую разобраться по готовности отпишусь! СПАСИБО Вам!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Покопался в [исходниках striprtf](https://github.com/joshy/striprtf/blob/73092d2322a8796444aee0c319e405ecdc770dbe/striprtf/striprtf.py#L150), нашел место, где кириллица превращается в кракозябры:

```
c = int(hex, 16)
if c > 127:
    out.append(chr(c))  # NOQA
else:
    out.append(chr(c))
```

Я ее заменил на (в `encoding` передавал `cp1251`):

```
c = int(hex, 16)
out.append(
    bytes([c]).decode(encoding)
)
```

---

И [сделал пример](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/tree/dc4400a4710dde784edb40b1b6e70fa212c2aab2/rtf_to_text__unicode) с небольшой доработкой (в `my_rtf_to_text` находится копия [исходника striprtf](https://github.com/joshy/striprtf/blob/73092d2322a8796444aee0c319e405ecdc770dbe/striprtf/striprtf.py#L150) с той доработкой, файл с текстом есть в примере):

```
from my_rtf_to_text import rtf_to_text

# NOTE: file header: {\rtf1\adeflang1025\ansi\ansicpg1251\
rtf = open('EULA_RUS.rtf', encoding='ansi').read()

print(
    rtf_to_text(rtf, encoding='cp1251')
)
# MICROSOFT SOFTWARE LICENSE TERMS
# MICROSOFT SQL SERVER COMPACT 4.0 SERVICE PACK 1 (SP1)
# Настоящие условия лицензии являются соглашением между корпорацией Microsoft (или, в зависимости от места вашего проживания, одним из ее аффилированных лиц) и вами. Прочтите их внимательно. Они применяются к вышеуказанному программному обеспечению, включая носители, на которых оно распространяется (если они есть). Эти условия распространяются также на все
# обновления,
# дополнительные компоненты,
# службы Интернета,
# службы технической поддержки
# Microsoft для данного программного обеспечения, если эти элементы не сопровождаются другими условиями. В последнем случае применяются соответствующие условия.
```

---

**PS.**

Пока искал информацию по `rtf to text`, узнал как определять кодировку с которой работать.

В начале файла `rtf` она указывается, например `{\rtf1\adeflang1025\ansi\ansicpg1251\` говорит что:

- сам файл закодирован `ansi` (по-моему, это кодировка по умолчанию)
- `ansicpg1251` -- текст кодируется в `cp1251` (`windows-1251`)

Comment: Просто СУПЕР!!!! СПАСИБО!!! ВЫ ЛУЧШИЙ!!!

Comment: @МаксимЦарьков, [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ и отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)

Comment: полезный пост `+`